# How to use visual transformation on Text in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I need to implement visual transformation in Text but somehow Text doesn't have this parameter only TextFiled does have this parameter. How to find solution about this?

Example;

```
TextField(
    visualTransformation = // have this parameter
)

Text(
    visualTransformation = // doesnt have this parameter
)
```

I need that because i have to show big decimal contains comma and dot seperator and i have visual transformation of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use your custom `VisualTransformation` class to transform your text before passing it to `Text`.

```
val visualTransformation = remember { CustomVisualTransformation() }
val transformedText = remember(value) {
    visualTransformation.filter(AnnotatedString(value))
}.text

Text(text = transformedText)
```